# Bootstrap 2.3.2 responsive layout doesn't work on IE8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

I'll try to be more specific. I have this stylesheets on my main control

```
 <link href="/css/Fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/css/mysite.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/explorer.css" />
        <![endif]-->

    <!-- css3-mediaqueries.js for IE less than 9 -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

my container width for large screen comes from responsive.css where I have this code

```
@media handheld, only screen and (min-width: 1440px){
      {.container:1400px;}
   }
```

when I run my code in crome it is 1400px for large screen ignoring bootstrap container width this

```
 @media (min-width: 1200px){
.container {
width: 1170px;}
}
```

and this

```
.container{
width: 940px;
}
```

but when I run my code in IE8 it picks up bootstrap container width

```
.container{
width: 940px;
}
```

and ignors

```
@media handheld, only screen and (min-width: 1440px){
{.container:1400px;} 
}
```

The problem is I want explorer 8 not to ignore my code for large sreen(1400px). I know I cannot add it in my  "explorer.css" as a media query inside a media query like this. i know it won't work.

```
/* IE8 */
@media \0screen
{
@media handheld, only screen and (min-width: 1440px){
.container:1400px;}

}
```

So  I decided to add !important on this

```
@media handheld, only screen and (min-width: 1440px){
{.container:1400px !important;}
}
```

so it began to be of the size I want for the large screen but now it resizes very slowly(due to css3-mediaqueries.js which works slowly) and is not showing up mobile design .So now my question is whether 
css3-mediaqueries.js supports mobile? Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Can you show us your sites code so we can work out what the issue is?